# Angular 9: ngOnChanges method of directive not triggered for attributes

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

I have a directive that sets the path of an svg.

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'svg use'
})
export class SvgDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input('attr.xlink:href') icon: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    const value = this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute('xlink:href');
    if (value) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('xlink:href', 'assets/svg-sprite.svg' + value);
      });
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (this.icon) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('xlink:href', 'assets/svg-sprite.svg' + this.icon);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Now ideally any element where this directive is specified and the input data is passed to this directive, ngOnChanges should be called.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="filterApplied ? '#filter-filled' : '#filter'""></use>
      </svg>
```

But the **ngOnChanges()** method is never triggered. **This is happening since I have upgared my Angular app to v9**